# OpenGL Use shader as filter

Tags: opengl, lwjgl, fbo

What is the standard procedure for using as a sort of filter in OpenGL? When I say filter I mean stuff like edge detection. For example, say I want to apply a SSAO filter to a FBO. Do I bind the FBO and depth buffer to a texture then draw a quad in front of the camera while using the shader while drawing to a seperate FBO? That's what I've been doing so far, but it's been sort of annoying. I want to know the common practice that most people use. I am probably missing something pretty big here. I am using LWJGL, so no glut if that matters.

Comment: Why do you find it annoying? How would you expect this to work in OpenGL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is exactly the common practice. Draw your scene into one or multiple textures (through the use of an FBO) then feed those texture into a filtering shader by drawing a textured screen-sized quad, rendering the results into either another texture (through use of another or the same FBO) or directly into the default (display) framebuffer when finished.

Nowadays (with OpenGL 4.3 hardware and drivers) you have yet another option. You can also employ a [*Compute Shader*](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Compute_Shader) for such tasks. This is basically a special kind of shader that in constrast to all the other shader stages is not part of the usual graphics pipeline, but exposes the generic GPGPU programming model (as known from CUDA or OpenCL) to OpenGL, while being able to use all OpenGL datastructures and functionality, like image load/store or texture filtering. (Well, in fact one could also use CUDA or OpenCL, which allow interoperation with OpenGL, but this is rather cumbersome and not worth it for tasks fitting so well to the graphics domain like image filtering. But compute shaders with their *zero* learning and interoperation overhead make this a usable alternative.)

Comment: I suppose I thought that simply drawing a screen sized quad would be "unprofessional" or something. At least now I don't have to change my code! Thanks for the extra info on Compute Shaders.

Comment: @Abaab Well, to some degree it's indeed a hack, misusing the graphics pipeline for non-graphics tasks (ok, image filtering is still graphics-related, but it doesn't really need the hardware's dedicated rasterization features and is really a classic GPGPU task). That's how GPGPU was done before CUDA...

Comment: @Abaab ...The proper (or *"professional"*) way to do it would be to use an actual computing framework (CUDA/OpenCL), but since we're already in an OpenGL application, the neccessary interoperation overhead (as in *"programming overhead"* rather than *"runtime overhead"*) is just not worth it. But fortunately compute shaders change this situation, since they nicely integrate into the rest of OpenGL and don't have any graphics-compute-interoperation overhead.

Comment: @Abaab ...But then again many common and classic techniques and algorithms from real-time computer graphics can be seen (or at least started) as hacks bending the graphics pipeline for tasks that it wasn't supposed to solve in the first place. Example: Why render the boundaries of a shadow volume with some weird stencil in- and decrementing and transformations to infinity, instead of just rendering the volume itself? Because your rasterizing graphics card doesn't render volumes but surfaces.

Comment: Yeah... graphics cards have gotten to be sort of "messy". I've been half-hoping for a giant random EM blast from the sun so we can wipe out all the messy, outdated stuff and start anew.

Comment: @Abaab Well, since unified shaders and compute you got that new start half-way already. The graphics pipeline nowadays is nothing more than a bunch of CUDA kernels executed on many small general purpose processors with some small bits of fixed function hardware in between. It's the software interface that still thinks in vertex and fragment shaders, but in the end that's what rasterization is about. Still rasterization is one of the best aproaches for real-time graphics (even if not the only one nowadays).

Answer (score 1):

That's how you do it, draw screen sized quads. You need to tell OpenGL which part of the screen you want filtered, and since OpenGL is a rasterizer, it needs to rasterize that part in order to know what to feed into the fragment shader, hence the quad.